# Printing url property not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble printing the property that I set in my url. Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.history.push("?timeperiod=Last 30 days")

   //the queryString is from: import queryString from "query-string"
   console.log(queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).timeperiod)
}
```

This prints out undefined but I can see that the value has been properly set in the url. How can I get this to print out properly? Thanks!

Comment: where is `this.props.location` coming from? what are you doing to pass location as a prop

Comment: What is the value of `this.props.location.search`? It's either defined and the problem is with `queryString.parse` or undefined, then the problem has nothing to do with `queryString.parse`. Either way the problem can be simplified.

Comment: I presume you are using react-router. look at this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-fun

Comment: @JoeyGough thanks lots that helped! I changed the `this.props.location.search` to `windows.location.search`. The reason why I had this.props was from a previous project that I was copying from...my bad